# JPanel How to make button work?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

As you read this code, you will realize I got one action event to work, it opens up a new JPanel that displays the button that will run the ballBounce, but for now im stuck trying to get a working button within that frame because that frame is already within a actionEvent, any help?

```
 public class MainJPanelOperation
    {
        public static void main(String[] a)
        {

            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 10, 1, 1));
            JButton t1 = new JButton();
            JButton t2 = new JButton();
            JButton letsStart = new JButton("Start The Program!");
            JButton t3 = new JButton();
            JButton t4 = new JButton();
            //letsStart.setBounds(200,250,12,12);
            panel1.add(t1);
            panel1.add(t2);
            panel1.add(letsStart);
            panel1.add(t3);
            panel1.add(t4);
            final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Game");
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.add(panel1);
            frame1.setSize(1000,1000);
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            t1.setVisible(false);
            t2.setVisible(false);
            t3.setVisible(false);
            t4.setVisible(false);
            letsStart.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            panel1.setBackground(Color.black);
            letsStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    System.out.println("panel 2 main menu intro online");
                    JPanel panelMM = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 10, 1, 0));
                    JButton MM1 = new JButton("BallBounce");
                    panelMM.add(MM1);
                    JFrame frameMM = new JFrame("Game/Main Menu");
                    frameMM.add(panelMM);
                    frameMM.setSize(1000,1000);
                    frameMM.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frameMM.setVisible(true);
                    frame1.setVisible(false);
                }
            });//end of start sequence

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JPanel panelMM = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 10, 1, 0));    
JButton MM1 = new JButton("BallBounce");
panelMM.add(MM1);
final JFrame frameMM = new JFrame("Game/Main Menu");
frameMM.add(panelMM);
frameMM.setSize(1000,1000);
frameMM.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

letsStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("panel 2 main menu intro 
                frameMM.setVisible(true);
                frame1.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

You can make frameMM final and there is no need to have all of your code inside the ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :it is working inside a Action Listener.

```
         JButton  MM1 = new JButton("BallBoe");
          MM1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
              System.out.println("panel 2");
            }
           });
```

or `class MainJPanelOperation implements ActionListener`

You can use `class MainJPanelOperation 
{ 
static JButton MM1;
//your code 
}`

```
       MM1=new JButton("Button");
       MM1.addActionListener(this);
```

write a Method outside Main()

```
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
    if(e.getSource()==MM1)
    {
     System.out.print("");
    }
   if(e.getSource()==Buttonobject)
   {
     //your code for button Pressing Event
   }
  }
```

Comment: so just add that below the line that makes the button? I figured I could do that, but that would become messy making action listeners all inside each other like that

Comment: static JButton MM1; makes a error: illegal start of expression

Comment: ok I got static working, but now I got a nullPointerException